# Forms: centering vertically

Tags: css, forms

At the current project I've one problem in forms. It is possible, that the font-size of a label in a form is higher then the default. If I raise it up, then the input on the right side must be centering vertically.

I took a look at Bootstrap and Foundation, but both hadn't a solution for this problem.

```
<form action="" class="m-form">
 <ol>
   <li>
     <label for="sample">A Sample Label</label>
     <input type="text" id="sample" class="m-form__textfield" value="A Sample Input">
   </li>
 </ol>
```

```
.m-form {
  ol {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  label:first-child {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding: .25em 2em .25em 0;
    width: 50%;

    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: right;
  }
  .m-form__textfield {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    float: left;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 50%;

    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
  }
}
```

}

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/qSNH5/1/

Do you have a simple solution for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using Vertical-Align Property

I made a few changes to your CSS:

```css
label:first-child {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: .25em 2em .25em 0;
    width: 40%;      
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1.5;
    text-align: right;
}
.m-form__textfield {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: .5em;
    width: 50%;               
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Instead of floating your elements, try using `display: inline-block` and then apply the `vertical-align: middle` property.

Be careful about the % width since the 50% values can cause the elements to wrap around into a second line depending on other factors such as padding, margin, borders and so on.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/AhZFm/

Comment: Oh man... This is it - I should go back in my holiday. Thanks for your help (y)

Comment: Glad to help! Please remember to accept the answer and welcome to SO!

Comment: inline-block is the way to go. But be aware of the space between both inline-block elements. When both elements are 50% you have to eliminate the space either in HTML (label and input in one line or <label><!-- linebreak --><input>) or with some tricky CSS (http://ksesocss.blogspot.com/2013/07/espacios-inline-block-solucion-universal.html use Google Translate). I prefer the HTML comments method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using `em` for the padding/margin so once you increase the `font-size` you also increase the padding/margin.

Try setting a fixed top/bottom padding to the label, that should help.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to center the input according to label you need to use a little trickery:

```
li{
 position: relative;

}

li input{
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -15px;
}
```

[SEE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/qSNH5/4/)

Comment: Thanks man, but it doesn't work for me. The input doesn't centering vertically.